# Advice with getIntegerArrayListExtra();

Tags: java, android, android-intent

Hi all I want to how to make this code works without serialization

here is my code:

```
List<Integer> k = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                for (int i = 0; i < MainActivity.lista_wybranych_towarow.size(); i++) {
                    k.add(towary.get(i).getTow_ilosc()-MainActivity.lista_wybranych_towarow.get(i).getTow_ilosc());

                }

                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        Zatwierdz.class);
                i.putIntegerArrayListExtra("rozmiar_listy", (ArrayList<Integer>) k);
                    //  String.valueOf(lista.get(j).size()));
                startActivity(i);
```

and here is what I'm trying to make in my next class where I pass data

```
ArrayList<Integer> rozmiar_listy = getIntent().getIntegerArrayListExtra(k);
```

But it doesn't work poperly. Why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use key which is `rozmiar_listy` instead of value  in next activity to get data from intent as :

```
ArrayList<Integer> rozmiar_listy = 
               getIntent().getIntegerArrayListExtra("rozmiar_listy");
```